# why theme.appcompat giving white background

Tags: android, android-source

I am using `android:theme=@style/AppTheme` for the application element in the manifest. The `style.xml` file defines this style as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

So I expect the background of the activities and menu options to be dark by default, but it is white. I have not defined any background attributes in my layouts. What is the problem?

Here is my analysis of the Android source :

1. There is no background color defined in `@style/Theme.AppCompat` or it's parent `@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat` according to [support themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml).
2. So i look at their parent `@android:style/Theme` at [base themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) . I see the below element :

   `<item name="colorBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>`
3. So i find out that the exact color of `background_dark` is `#ff000000` according to [colors.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml)

Why is Android not using this colour for my activities?

Comment: I think it varies among different OS versions, because colors are defined differently (i.e.: `@android:color/background_dark`). Try to customize your theme and give it the colors you want. And... +1 for spotting out the `values-1x` problem - I really forgot about that!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein you are right..it was an OS version problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the the `styles.xml` in `values-v11` and `values-v14` were using `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Since my phone has API 19, it picks up these themes instead of from the `values` folder, which had the `styles.xml` with `Theme.AppCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I change theme in `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updateTheme();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blablabla);
}
```

I fix it by change order of `updateTheme` and `super.onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    updateTheme();        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blablabla);
});
```